# What are the eight segments between sunrise and sunset called in Vedic Astrology?

Tags: astrology

I know that the time between sunrise and sunset is divided into 8 segments. 
One of the segment is called RahuKalam. The other two are Gulika kalam and Yamanagandam. 
What are the other 5 segments called? If they have any name as such.

Comment: ashta praharas?

Comment: The ashta praharas are the time between sunrise to next sunrise divided by 8 right ? Whereas what I am referring is the time divided by sunrise to sunset by 8. I think it is called Yamas but I have not found any details regarding it.

Comment: Yes you are right .. prahara is approximately 3 hrs long.

Comment: Do share if you have any details about Yamas of a day.

Comment: Yes I will do for sure if I find anything. I remember reading something relevant in a hard copy Panjika.

Comment: I have posted an answer. But I don't have any scriptural references. This is the max that I can do here

Comment: And if its not useful tell me, I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As I have said in a comment, I read about it in a Panjika (an astrological Panchang). It's a hard copy of Benimadhava's Panjika. I have verified with another Panjika (of Madana Gupta) and both are in agreement.

- **Definition of Kalabela (KB) and  Barabela (BB).**

If we divide the duration of a day (which is roughly 12 hours) into 8 equal parts, each such part is called a "Yamardha" (not Yama mind you but half of that).

Of these parts, certain are considered as inauspicious for doing any events in them. These are called Barabela and Kalabela. When they come during the seven days of a week are listed below.

> - Sunday - 4th (BB); 5th (KB)
> - Monday - 7th (BB); 2nd (KB)
> - Tuesday - 2nd (BB); 6th (KB)
> - Wednesday - 5th (BB); 3rd (KB)
> - Thursday - 8th (BB) ; 7th (KB)
> - Friday - 3rd (BB) ; 4th (KB)
> - Saturday - 1st, 6th (BB); 8th (KB)

- **Definition of Kalaratri**

We have a similar concept for the night too. The night too is approximately 12 hours long and if the duration is divided into 8 equal parts, then each such part is called a "Kalaratri". When this particular time period comes during each night for the seven days are listed below:

> - Sunday - 6th
> - Monday - 4th
> - Tuesday - 2nd
> - Wednesday - 7th
> - Thursday - 5th
> - Friday - 3rd
> - Saturday - 1st and 8th.

Note that, only Saturday has two Barabelas and two Kalaratris.

As already mentioned, from the astrological standpoint, these timings are to be  avoided for starting any auspicious events.

These information are found in a sub-section of the Panjikas, called Jyotisha Vachanartha.

Comment: Names of the various periods are not mentioned. Only specified which ones fall under the inauspicious groups - Kalabela, Barabela and Kalaratri.

Comment: Thanks. So all the segments are not named.

Comment: Yes, not mentioned in the source I used. But may be somewhere else the names are mentioned. @Echo You never know