# Gulika, Yamaganda and Ardhaprahara kala

Tags: astrology

What are the exact definitions and calculations related to Gulika, Yamganda and Ardhaprahara Kalas? Which are auspicious and which inauspicious?

I think Rahu Kala is already answered on this site, but the other three popular kalas are not. I think except Gulika, the other kalas are inauspicious. Could someone give the exact muhurta in the daytime when a particular kala is named with respect to sunrise and sunset? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The following answer might be helpful -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40916